# How do you set the "current image" as far as bpy is concerned?

Tags: python, scripting, image, command-line

How do you set the current image ( or current anything for that matter ) from a script or command console? I want to use something like

```
bpy.ops.image.reload()
```

which apparently works on the current image.

Comment: Did either of these answers help you at all?

Comment: Yes and No. I am a blender newbie, so Yes, any input from experienced users helps. No because I can't get past this issue of getting an Image Displace modifier to work without a GUI.I have a script that opens a .blend file, changes the image ( thank you for help with this ) , then exports an STL file, supposedly applying modifiers. When running blender from command line the script works in "foreground", won't modify with "--background"

Answer (score 3):

Unlike 3d view where you can only have one active object no matter how many views are open, the image editor is not restricted to that. From a UI standpoint you could have multiple UV/ImageEditor windows open, and then the concept of 'current image' starts to require more context. This is the case even if you had one image window open, or *none* when running in background mode. Luckily we don't need to worry about current image, or loop through views.

**Use the right API calls**

instead of calling operators intended to be called by the UI, it's often more convenient to manipulate Image datablocks directly using the methods provided by the [Image class](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Image.html). You can use:

```
import bpy

# make an alias to increase readability.
images = bpy.data.images

# if the image changes on disk, this should get the new pixels
images[image_name].reload()

# the same can be done using .load()
images.load("/home/zeffii/Desktop/some_image.png", check_existing=True)
```

As explained in [your other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43348/47)

**Don't do this if you can avoid it**

https://gist.github.com/zeffii/54410dcbff9b6aa4953d

```
import bpy

images = bpy.data.images

# say I know I have 2 images, and 2 IMAGE_EDITORS open
# currently none of the image editors are showing any image.
loaded_images = images[:]

AREA = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    for area in window.screen.areas:

        if not area.type == AREA:
            continue

        for s in area.spaces:
            if s.type == AREA:
                image_to_use = loaded_images.pop()
                # s.image is the property to set for each
                # IMAGE_EDITOR to tell it to display a certain 
                # image by reference.
                s.image = image_to_use
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to reload an image datablock. You don't need to set it to be the current image.

Accessing the datablock can be done in a few different ways. If you know the name of the image datablock (usually the image name but can be changed), you can target it that way. Or if you know the path to the image on your os, you can loop through the bpy.data.images array and find it that way.

```
import bpy

#direct access by datablock name
bpy.data.images['image.png'].reload()

#find image datablock by image filepath and reload
for i in bpy.data.images:
    if i.filepath=="/path/to/image.png":
        i.reload()
```