# How do I convert an image from my file to the blender?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I have tried doing this for example

```
    bpy.ops.image.open(filepath="//../flags/6.png", directory="/Users/shak/Desktop/flags/", files=[{"name":"6.png", "name":"6.png"}], show_multiview=False)
```

But that didn't work.

My pathname should be correct and blender writes exactly this. But I can't seem to be able to put an image into a plane with code.

Does anyone know what can I do about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't load an image from a script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43345/i-cant-load-an-image-from-a-script)

Comment: Hello! Thank of the reply! I loaded the image into the blender. How do I then use it to change the plane image? I tried reload() and my code above, but it didn't seem to work. Console wrote bpy.data.images['1.png'], but I am not sure how do I then change the image of the plane.

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign an image to a plane, is that right?

Try this:

```
import bpy

image = bpy.data.images.load("C:\\Path_to_image\\images.jpg")

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
plane = bpy.context.object

plane.scale = (image.size[0]/100, image.size[1]/100, 1)

mat = bpy.data.materials.new("Material")
mat.use_nodes = True

tex_ = mat.node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexImage')
tex_.image = image


principled_ = None
for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
    if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
        principled_ = node
        break

if not principled_:
    principled_ = mat.node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')


mat.node_tree.links.new(principled_.inputs[0], tex_.outputs[0])

output_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
mat.node_tree.links.new(output_node.inputs[0], principled_.outputs[0])


plane.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Let me know if this is what you want to achieve, the question wasn't very clear for me.